# Travelling Sales Man: Finding Total Shortest Distance Travelled To All Points Without Going Back To Origin (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, nearest-neighbor, traveling-salesman

This is a school project, where we are supposed to find the total shortest distance travelled to all points once, without going back to the origin. I have solved this using the nearest neighbour method, however, sometimes it will not give the fastest route. Is there any algorithms I can use to solve this? I wanted to try using 2-Opt Swap however that requires all points to be connected.

Here is my main code:

```
// Mini Proj.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

// #pragma warning(disable : 4996) // turn off warnings for error code
using namespace std;

int numArr[20]; // Set to 20 for redundancy, in case there's a lot of locations

// Display Code Keilaash
int rack_length;
int rack_height;
int id = 49;

// typedef for easier use.
typedef vector<vector<char>> Matrix;
typedef vector<char> Row;

// Class to hold Location's X and Y value
class Location
{
public:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;

    Location()
    {
        m_x = -1;
        m_y = -1;
    };
    Location(int x, int y)
    {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    };
};

/* Make matrix of all 0s. */
void setup_matrix(Matrix &matrix) // Matrix is access matrix[y][x]
{
    // asigning values, I suppose this is done allready.
    for ( int y = rack_height-1 ; y >= 0 ; y-- ) // start from top left
    {
        vector<char> row(rack_length);

        for (int x = 0; x < rack_length; x++)
        {
            row[x] = '0';
        }
        matrix.push_back(row);
    }

}

/* Initialise matrix with home and points */
void preset_matrix(int x, int y, Matrix &matrix) // Set X then set Y
{
    matrix[0][0] = 'H';
    matrix[y][x] = 'X';
}

/* mark location as being visited. */
void update_matrix(int x, int y, Matrix &matrix) // Set X then Set Y
{
    matrix[y][x] = id ;
    id++;
}

/* display the matrix on the screen */
void display_matrix(Matrix &matrix)
{
    // matrix is accessed as matrix[y][x]
    cout << "\nMatrix Output:" << endl;

    for (int y = rack_height-1 ; y >= 0 ; y--)  // loop 3 times for three lines
    {
        for (int x = 0 ; x < rack_length ; x++)  // loop for the three elements on the line
        {
            cout << matrix[y][x];  // display the current element out of the array
        }
        cout << endl;  // when the inner loop is done, go to a new line
    }
    cout << endl;
}



int main()
{
    int numElements;

    ifstream readIn;
    string fileName;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        numArr[i] = i;
    }

    cout << "What is the name of the file you would like to open (please include the .txt extension): ";
    cin >> fileName;

    readIn.open(fileName.c_str()); // Open text file for subsequent information retrieval

    // Error check, to notify the user if there was trouble opening the file 
    if (!readIn)
    {
        cout << "There was an error opening the file you wanted" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int inputCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            readIn >> numArr[i];
            if (readIn)
            {
                inputCount++;
            }
        }
        inputCount -= 2;
        // cout << inputCount << endl; // Count the number of individual co-ordinates that were put into the text file (Xi, Yi) 

        cout << "Total X length: " << numArr[0] << endl;
        cout << "Total Y length: " << numArr[1] << endl;

        int y = 2, z = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputCount; i++)
        {
            if (i < inputCount / 2)
            {
                cout << "Location " << i + 1 << ": " << numArr[y] << ", " << numArr[z] << endl;
                y += 2;
                z += 2;
            }
        }
        // Save data into variables
        rack_length = numArr[0];
        rack_height = numArr[1];
        numElements = inputCount;
    }

    /* List of Location */
    list<Location> locationList, sortedLocationList;
    list<Location>::iterator it, iteratorShortest;

    /* Create list of locations */
    vector<int> xCoordinates;
    vector<int> yCoordinates;

    // Transfer xy from array to vectors
    for (int i = 2; i < numElements + 2; i++) 
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) // even
        {
            xCoordinates.push_back(numArr[i]);
        }
        else // odd
        {
            yCoordinates.push_back(numArr[i]);
        }
    }

    /* Safety Checks */
    // ensure proper tally of x and y coordinates
    if ( xCoordinates.size() != yCoordinates.size() )
    {
        cout << "\nNumber of x and y coordinates do not match" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // ensure rack size larger than points in rack.
    double maxXCoordinate = *max_element(xCoordinates.begin(), xCoordinates.end()); // max element returns iterator
    double maxYCoordinate = *max_element(yCoordinates.begin(), yCoordinates.end()); // max element returns iterator
    if (maxXCoordinate > rack_length || maxYCoordinate > rack_height)
    {
        cout << "\nYour xy coordinate is not in rack_length or rack_height" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int numberOfLocations = xCoordinates.size();

    Matrix matrix;
    setup_matrix(matrix);

    // initialise Location nodes for algorthim and display
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLocations; i++)
    {
        Location location(xCoordinates[i], yCoordinates[i]);
        locationList.push_back(location);

        preset_matrix(xCoordinates[i], yCoordinates[i], matrix);
    }


    /* Greedy Algorithm */
    int currentX = 0;
    int currentY = 0;
    int listSize = locationList.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    {
        int shortestDistance = -1; // -1 indicates undefined

        // reset iterator
        iteratorShortest = locationList.begin();

        // Loops through location list, finding the shortest distance from start location to next location.
        for (it = locationList.begin(); it != locationList.end(); it++)
        {
            // Find Difference in X and Y coordinates
            int xDiff = abs((*it).m_x - currentX);
            int yDiff = abs((*it).m_y - currentY);
            int distance = xDiff + yDiff;

            if (distance < shortestDistance || shortestDistance == -1)
            {
                //cout << "new shortest distance found " << distance << endl; //DEBUG
                shortestDistance = distance;

                // save shortest element's iterator
                iteratorShortest = it;
            }
            else
            {
                //cout << "not longer" << endl; //DEBUG
            }
        }
        // add location to sorted list
        sortedLocationList.push_back(*iteratorShortest);

        /* Reset algortihm to find next closest node*/
        // set new value for current x and y
        currentX = (*iteratorShortest).m_x;
        currentY = (*iteratorShortest).m_y;

        // Remove found element from list
        locationList.erase(iteratorShortest);
    }



    /* Display list of locations */
    display_matrix(matrix);

    for (it = sortedLocationList.begin(); it != sortedLocationList.end(); it++)
    {
        update_matrix( (*it).m_x , (*it).m_y , matrix);
        display_matrix(matrix);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is my text file named rack1.txt:

```
10
10
6
0
2
3
4
1
4
4
6
7
6
1
7
1
```

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: For small instances, you can solve this as a MIP (Mixed-Integer Programming) model. For large problems, there are no simple algorithms that prove optimality. Meta-heuristics to a reasonable job, but have no notion of optimality.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen And how would that be done exactly? Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I suggest to use Google. There must be a million references for this. Eg TSP MIP gives a ton of results.